# Framebuffer not working on startup but then works fine

Tags: opengl-es, framebuffer

A framebuffer is created in my App.
Every time I uninstall the app and then run it again via eclipse it does not work. But every time after that I run it via eclipse it does work! So on a fresh install it never works first time but when I run the app again its fine. Any ideas? Thanks

```
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, temp2, 0);
fboTex = temp2[0];
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTex);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 1024, 512, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, temp, 0);
MyGLRenderer.fboId = temp[0];
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, MyGLRenderer.fboId);
GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboTex, 0);
GLES20.glGenRenderbuffers(1, temp3, 0);
renderBufferId = temp3[0];
GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferId);
GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, MyGLRenderer.mFboW, MyGLRenderer.mFboH);
GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBufferId);
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: To get help here you need to give more info: What do mean by "doesn't work? Why do you post so little piece of code?

Comment: How do you install the app?

Comment: Sorry - I posted the entire framebuffer creation code. I am using the code to render water to, then apply effects and then render to the screen. I am installing via eclipse. On startup the water just does not work, nothing is rendered. But when I try again it work fine.

Comment: It's still completely unclear to me how you conclude that the framebuffer is the problem and not the water rendering or the effects.

Comment: well it might be that - I have no idea. But the other code is so simple its hard to imagine it could be that.

Comment: Have you tried adding error checking. glGetError, glCheckFramebufferStatus, etc.